# Setting up local players in Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, unreal

I'm trying to make a 4 player 2D local multiplayer game.

I have tried a lot of stuff to get to this stage, but as far as I have been told, a method called `CreateLocalPlayer` creates a local player, creates a controller and spawns an actor into the game... It sounded good so I gave it a try:

**Inside my game mode `StartPlay()`**

```
void AGeneralGameMode::LoadPlayers()
{
    if (GetMaxPlayerCount())
    {
        UWorld* currentWorld = GetWorld();

        UGameInstance* gameInstance = currentWorld->GetGameInstance();
        UGameViewportClient* gameViewport = currentWorld->GetGameViewport();

        // Remove split screen because I want a 2D game
        gameViewport->SetDisableSplitscreenOverride(true);

        for (int32 a = 1; a <= GetMaxPlayerCount(); a++)
        {

            FString error;
            ULocalPlayer* localPlayer = gameInstance->CreateLocalPlayer(a, error, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Before i get to the problem of the above, **I could forsee two issues** anyway... **How could I convert the controller and the actor(pawn) created for me by CreateLocalPlayer to the types i have made myself**...

I was told to place the following code inside the game mode construct:

```
AGeneralGameMode::AGeneralGameMode(const FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer)
    : Super(ObjectInitializer)
{
    // set default pawn class to our character
    DefaultPawnClass = ABasePlayer::StaticClass();
}
```

This does get called, but the ABasePlayer class I have never has a Possess statement trigger it... and thus my virtual override never gets called for Input stuff:

```
// ABasePlayer
virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* InputComponent) override;
```

**My question is, what is the procedure to create 4 local players...**

Feel free to gather more context from this conversation:   https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?56494-How-do-you-place-APlayerCharacter-onto-APlayerStart-and-take-control

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

This is my current understanding of what is happening... is this atleast right?

[image]